# Acceptable to use a Type for a Dictionary Key?

Tags: c#, data-structures, dictionary, .net-3.5

I would like to make a class that can store at most one copy of an object. All the objects stored here will share the same base class, and I would like to be able to get an object based on it's type.

I've come up with this solution so far, but I feel like I'm doing something wrong with using a Type for the Dictionary key.

Base class used in multiple modules

```
interface ISessionVariables { }
```

Example of common singleton class used for accessing

```
public class SessionVariables
{
    private object _sync = new object();
    private Dictionary<Type, ISessionVariables> _sessionVariables = 
        new Dictionary<Type, ISessionVariables>;

    public T Get<T>()
        where T : ISessionVariable, new()
    {
        lock (_sync)
        {
            ISessionVariables rtnValue = null;
            if (_sessionVariables.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out rtnValue))
                return (T)rtnValue;

            rtnValue = new T();
            _sessionVariables.Add(typeof(T), rtnValue);

            return (T)rtnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can call it like this from individual modules

```
SessionVariableSingleton.Get<ModuleASessionVars>().PropertyA;

SessionVariableSingleton.Get<ModuleCSessionVars>().PropertyC;
```

Is this an acceptable way of storing this kind of data structure? Or is there a better alternative using a List or a dictionary without a Type key?

Comment: I don't see any problems with what you've decided to do.

Comment: For two days now I have been writing code very much similar to yours. I haven't found any problems with it. Yet. If it makes you feel better (safer), just use the name of the `Type` instead.

Comment: Looks good to me. Thinking of it as a dictionary might feel odd but when you see it as a hash map I think it feels like it fits.

Comment: Since this is working fine, have you thought about asking over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: For info, I edited the static cache implementation in my answer to be *insanely* simple, while offering full thread-safety. Sometimes, the simpler you make it, the better - this is one of those times.

Answer (score 13):

Yes `Type` is fine as a key; thread-safety is a concern, though - in many ways `Hashtable` is better at threaded-scenarios. However, there is a better option since you are using generics: ***cheat***:

```
class SessionVariables {
    static class Cache<T> where T : ISessionVariable, new() {
        public static readonly ISessionVariable Value = new T();
    }
    ISessionVariable Get<T>() where T : ISessionVariable, new() {
        return Cache<T>.Value;
    }
}
```

Which is now fully thread-safe (without "returned different instances" issues) **without** any dictionary costs.

---

Edit on the topic of `Hashtable` for Jon:

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` makes no guarantees on concurrency, so you are required to synchronize *all* access - including the *reads*, as another thread doing a *write* can break a reader (you ***can*** force this in an example, but like most thread-races, it is hard to reproduce).

By contract, `Hashtable` guarantees that it is safe for **any number of readers**, plus at most one writer. From MSDN:

> Hashtable is thread safe for use by multiple reader threads and a single writing thread. It is thread safe for multi-thread use when only one of the threads perform write (update) operations, which allows for lock-free reads provided that the writers are serialized to the Hashtable.

This means that you can do things like:

```
var val = (SomeType)hash[key];
if(val == null) {
   // not there; actually compute / create the value
   val = ...
   // and store it for the next access
   lock(syncLock) {
       hash[key] = val; // note: could do double-check here
   }
}
return val;
```

Notice that the *read* cycle above does not require any synchronization; only the *writes* need to be synchronized. Note also that because `Hashtable` uses `object`, it works best when the keys and values are classes (not structs).

Yes, concurrent dictionaries now exist - but the above *works just fine*.

Comment: Not sure about your `Hashtable` comment - could you elaborate? I like the generic cache, although of course it only works properly when it *is* used as a singleton - creating a new instance of `SessionVariables` will give the same variables back. Also, I'm not sure why you haven't just restricted `T` in `Cache<T>` and used a static initializer - then it would always return the same instance with no safety issues. (Although in that case if the constructor failed, you wouldn't get to try again.)

Comment: @Jon added more detail on `Hashtable`

Comment: @Jon I fixed the false-singleton issue, btw; much simpler and better now

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know that about `Hashtable`. I wonder what the difference is internally...

Comment: @Jon we really need to create a new gold medal for any time you say "I didn't know that". We wouldn't need to award it very often, I suspect ;p

Comment: Thanks, I like this implementation. It won't work with what I am doing now since I had planned on adding save/load functionality eventually, but I will definitely keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 8):

There's one issue: it's not thread-safe. Given that you appear to be using this via a singleton, I'd imagine you *do* need it to be thread-safe.

If you're using .NET 4, you'd be best off using [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx). Otherwise, add locking.

The `ConcurrentDictionary` code would look like this:

```
internal class SessionVariables
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ISessionVariables> dictionary
        = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ISessionVariables>();

    internal ISessionVariable Get<T>() where T : ISessionVariable, new()
    {
        return dictionary.GetOrAdd(typeof(T), _ => new T());
    }
}
```

(I'd also avoid singletons where possible, but that's a different matter.)

EDIT: To specifically address using a type as a dictionary key: yes, that's fine. In fact, you're fine with reference equality, as `Type` objects are effectively canonically - there's only one `Type` object to represent a particular type in a particular `AppDomain`, no matter how you ask for it. (This *may* not be true in dynamically generated assemblies using CodeDOM... not sure. But it should be fine for the normal case.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using .Net 3.5 and my intention was to use a lock object in the `Get<T>` method. I just left it out of the question for simplicity.

Comment: @Rachel: Well if you're asking whether there's anything wrong with the code, leaving out something which makes it safe is a bit odd... please give more complete information in future.

Comment: @JonSkeet I will, thank you. I've also updated my post to include the locking and the .net 3.5 tag, although I will definitely keep `ConcurrentDictionary` in mind for if I'm ever using 4.0. I was mostly concerned about using a Type for a dictionary key, but it seems like that's perfectly acceptable. :)